# what is the difference between "imagine" and "envision"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I kind like a word "envision" so, Can I use it exactly in same way as a word "imagine"?

Answer (score 3):

In Britain we seldom use a verb *envision*. We say *envisage*.

However *envisage* and *imagine* are not direct synonyms. As any good dictionary will tell you, whilst *imagine* refers to forming a mental image of something; *envisage* means to contemplate or conceive of something as a possible future event. The following two sentences are taken as examples from the Oxford Dictionary Online.

*She imagined him at his desk, his head in his hands*.

*The Rome treaty envisaged free movement across frontiers*.

For Americans you can substitute *envision* for where the English would use *envisage*.

Answer (score 1):

They are very similar words, but the connotation is different.

Imagine has the connotation of something clearly fake, fantastical, or hypothetical.

Envision is asking you to be a more active participant in the fantasy, but asking you to seriously consider that XYZ *might* be possible/feasible.  I believe this supported by breaking apart the term:

[**en-**: “to cause (a person or thing) to be in”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/en-)

[**vision**: a supernatural appearance that conveys a revelation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vision)

**So to a certain extent envisioning is asking someone to prophesize with you. Of course a non-believer will reply you're just imagining things....**

Here is a simple example:

> Imagine living in a castle floating in the clouds.
>
> Envision living in a castle floating in the clouds.

As you can see the meaning is largely the same but the tone is different. When I imagine my castle it is clear this is a pipe dream. When I'm asked to envision it I'm being asked to consider the possibility that I could live in my castle. This is further backed up by marketing ploys like:

> Imagine that you could earn $100k per year working only an hour a day from home. Now let me show you how you can make that dream a reality.

Contrast that with the rhetoric employed by the wealth via visualization technique believers. They never use the word *imagine*. They use words like *visualize*, *envision*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

They are synonyms, but "envision" is much less common and sounds more formal:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=envision%2C%20imagine%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenvision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimagine%3B%2Cc0): ***imagine vs envision***

A note from the ***[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/envision-invision/)***:

> - ***Envision (which is different from "envisage") is the standard spelling of the verb meaning to picture in the mind or imagine.*** ***Invision*** is an alternate spelling that is no longer in use.
> - A 1913 Webster’s unabridged dictionary lists a separate noun sense of invision: lack of vision or the power of seeing. But we can’t find any examples of the word used this way.

***[Envision vs envisage](http://grammarist.com/usage/envision-envisage/)*** :

> - Both envision and envisage mean to visualize, but they differ slightly in connotation.
> - ***To envisage*** is to contemplate or consider something—usually something real—in a certain way, or to predict a particular set of circumstances based on evidence or strong belief.
> - ***Envisaging*** often relates to planning real-world projects. ***When you envision something,*** it’s usually more hypothetical, imaginary, or removed from reality.
> - ***The difference is subtle, but think of it this way: Envisaging usually involves something real, while envisioning involves mostly imaginary elements.*** You might envision a distant goal that you have not begun to work toward. Later, as you plan how to reach that goal, you might envisage how you’re going to do it with the time and resources you have available.

Comment: I would be interested to know how the *Grammarist* thinks *envision* differs from *envisage*. The OED includes *envisage* as part of the explanation of *envision*, though not vice-versa. I think there is little difference except that *envision* is the American term that means *envisage*.

Comment: In your updated answer *Envision vs envisage*, please can you give us the source of this quotation. It is not a distinction in meaning that I recognise, perhaps because I am British. But having worked with Americans for a lot of my life, I have little recollection of their using *envisage* at all.

Comment: All links and sources are present in my answer.

Comment: Interesting that not one of the examples of *envision* comes from a British source. It seems to confirm to me that the difference in usage of the words is primarily regional.